# How to determine the aspect ratio of an image or pdf?

Tags: pdf

Is there a unix binary that has a command to determine the aspect ratio of an image or a pdf file? (letter, A4, etc.)

Comment: "Letter" and "A4" are not aspect ratios, there are specific physical dimensions. Are you after "_this will scale up/down and fit 'perfectly' on A4_", or are you after "_this is A4_".

Comment: For image files you need an exif viewer....https://en.softonic.com/downloads/exif

Comment: Fastest solution is Media Info, it puts a right click menu for images and video files in the context menu, reboot before it shows up in the context menu.......https://sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo/

Comment: Aspect ratio vs dimensions: the latter determine the former, no? Yes, 'this is A4' would be even more useful than the aspect ratio. Is exiftool the ux binary corresponding to exif? It does return the image size for an image, not a pdf. I guess I could first convert the first page to an image...